# Display markdown images as links

Tags: php, markdown

I'm using Michel Fortin's [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) for Markdown converting but i want to show images as links instead of inline. Because anyone can insert a 5MB jpg from Imgur and slow down page.

How can i change images to link-to-image?

Comment: I have tried Regular Expressions, good old str_ireplace and substr. But image can alt text and title, or only title etc. There is not just one condition. And also str_ireplace changed img texts inside code blocks too. I am also ashamed to confess but i even tried to change result HTML DOM with XML tools but i give up because it's not  a viable option.

Comment: Instead of trying to do your stuff after the conversion have you considered looking into the source of markdown and searching for idunno a method called [`doImages()`](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/lib/Michelf/Markdown.php#L646)?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't know how I did forget simple OO principles :) I think i can override _doImages_reference_callback function and achieve what i want :) thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an override would look something like the follwing:

```
class CustomMarkdown extends Markdown
{
    function _doImages_reference_callback($matches) {
        $whole_match = $matches[1];
        $alt_text    = $matches[2];
        $link_id     = strtolower($matches[3]);

        if ($link_id == "") {
            $link_id = strtolower($alt_text); # for shortcut links like ![this][].
        }

        $alt_text = $this->encodeAttribute($alt_text);
        if (isset($this->urls[$link_id])) {
            $url = $this->encodeAttribute($this->urls[$link_id]);
            $result = "<a href=\"$url\">$alt_text</a>";
        } else {
            # If there's no such link ID, leave intact:
            $result = $whole_match;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function _doImages_inline_callback($matches) {
        $whole_match    = $matches[1];
        $alt_text       = $matches[2];
        $url            = $matches[3] == '' ? $matches[4] : $matches[3];
        $title          =& $matches[7];

        $alt_text = $this->encodeAttribute($alt_text);
        $url = $this->encodeAttribute($url);
        return "<a href=\"$url\">$alt_text</a>";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VVa2hP

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/). It is a more recent and, I believe, easier to extend implementation of Markdown.